# Flatten nested JSON string to different columns in Google BigQuery

Tags: python, json, pandas, google-bigquery

I have column in one of the BigQuery table which looks like this.

```
{"name": "name1", "last_delivered": {"push_id": "push_id1", "time": "time1"}, "session_id": "session_id1", "source": "SDK", "properties": {"UserId": "u1"}}
```

Is there any was to get the output like this in GBQ ?? (basically flatten the entire column into different columns)

```
name    last_delivered.push_id   last_delivered.time   session_id   source   properties.UserId

name1       push_id1                     time1         session_id1   SDK          uid1
```

Let's say

> a = {"name": "name1", "last_delivered": {"push_id": "push_id1",
>   "time": "time1"}, "session_id": "session_id1", "source": "SDK",
>   "properties": {"UserId": "u1"}}

I have tried to get desired output in Pandas Python using **json_normalize(a)** , but every time I try get the following error

[image]

Does anyone has any idea how can I get my desired output. Am I missing something ??

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I copied your code into Spyder 3.6 and it works as you want it to:
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
a = {"name": "name1", "last_delivered": {"push_id": "push_id1", "time": "time1"}, "session_id": "session_id1", "source": "SDK", "properties": {"UserId": "u1"}}
b = json_normalize(a)
b
Out[5]: 
  last_delivered.push_id last_delivered.time  ...     session_id source
0               push_id1               time1  ...    session_id1    SDK

Comment: `json_normalize` works for me.

Comment: works fine for me as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess as to why it's not working is that your json data is actually a string:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 

a = '''{"name": "name1", "last_delivered": {"push_id": "push_id1", "time": "time1"}, "session_id": "session_id1", "source": "SDK", "properties": {"UserId": "u1"}}'''  

df = json_normalize(a)
```

**Output:**

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Versus:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 

a = {"name": "name1", "last_delivered": {"push_id": "push_id1", "time": "time1"}, "session_id": "session_id1", "source": "SDK", "properties": {"UserId": "u1"}}  

df = json_normalize(a)
```

**Output:**

```
 print(df.to_string())
  last_delivered.push_id last_delivered.time   name properties.UserId   session_id source
0               push_id1               time1  name1                u1  session_id1    SDK
```

If this is the case, you can use `json.loads()` right before normalize:

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

a = '''{"name": "name1", "last_delivered": {"push_id": "push_id1", "time": "time1"}, "session_id": "session_id1", "source": "SDK", "properties": {"UserId": "u1"}}'''  

data = json.loads(a)
df = json_normalize(data)
```

Comment: This works fine, thanks mate!!....but, I have scaled down the problem here. Let's say we have a data frame with one column having such values. **json.loads()** accepts only a single string value. I know I can keep it in a **for** loop, but the problem is the data frame has millions of rows....I think it will take a lot of time if we go by this way. Any other way ??...have been trying from my side too.

Comment: Just tested with 10k rows by keeping it in **for** loop...god! it took more than ~30 min. Well, the output is what I am expecting. There are more than million rows for each day and I wanted to do this on daily basis. With the computing power of BQ machines I strongly feel those machines can do a lot faster, provided the feasibility should be there.

Answer (score 4):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '{"name": "name1", "last_delivered": {"push_id": "push_id1", "time": "time1"}, "session_id": "session_id1", "source": "SDK", "properties": {"UserId": "u1"}}' col
)
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(col, '$.name') name,
  STRUCT(
    JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(col, '$.last_delivered.push_id') AS push_id,
    JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(col, '$.last_delivered.time') AS time
  ) last_delivered,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(col, '$.session_id') session_id,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(col, '$.source') source,
  STRUCT(
    JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(col, '$.properties.UserId') AS UserId
  ) properties
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

and produces result as expected/asked

```
Row name    last_delivered.push_id  last_delivered.time session_id  source  properties.UserId    
1   name1   push_id1                time1               session_id1 SDK     u1
```

Comment: I knew this solution, but I want the columns to be dynamic. Let's say for other rows there are more properties and for some of them there are less values. I didn't go for this because it's too manual I feel. Well, if nothing works this is the only solution I should go for. Thanks, anyways :)

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. Any thought on whether it is possible in google big query ??...dynamic flatten.

Comment: usually this type of things are done with client of your choice, like python. if you want this to be done purely in BQ - you will need to approach it in two steps - first to generate sql text and then execute it. I think this two-steps approach will be doable  - but because of limited json support for bq  - it will be over-complicated  - so I think using client approach - is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

```
with jsonstring as (
select * from (
  select id,actor, json_extract(events, "$[0]") as events, 
  row_number() over (partition by id order by record_ingestion_time desc) as rno  FROM efficacy_gdrive.gdrive_events
  ) where rno = 1
),
parsed_json AS (
SELECT id, actor, PARSE_JSON(events) AS  jsondata from jsonstring
),
stg as (
SELECT 
  id, 
  actor,
  STRUCT(
    JSON_VALUE(jsondata, "$.name") AS name,
    JSON_VALUE(jsondata, "$.type") AS type,
    ARRAY(
      SELECT STRUCT(
      JSON_VALUE(parameter, '$.name') AS name,
      JSON_VALUE(parameter, '$.value') AS value
      )
      FROM UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(jsondata, "$.parameters")) AS parameter
    ) AS parameters
  ) AS data
FROM parsed_json)
SELECT 
 JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(actor, '$.email') as user,
 CAST(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(id, '$.time') as TIMESTAMP) as DATETIME) as event_time,
 data.name as name,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(data.parameters) WHERE name = 'doc_id') AS doc_id,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(data.parameters) WHERE name = 'owner') AS owner,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(data.parameters) WHERE name = 'doc_type') AS doc_type,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(data.parameters) WHERE name = 'doc_title') AS doc_title,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(data.parameters) WHERE name = 'visibility') AS visibility,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(data.parameters) WHERE name = 'originating_app_id') AS originating_app_id,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(data.parameters) WHERE name = 'shared_drive_id') AS shared_drive_id
from stg
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).